# C# Concurrent Dictionary not saving my List<string> value between page loads

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

It's been a while since I've been this stumped.  The crazy thing is, I've done this several times in other areas of my code, so it's almost complete copy and paste, but except this code isn't working properly.  so I am somehow missing something extremely obvious.

```
public class RoomCache
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> _dicOnlineTraders;
    ILoggingService _logService = new LoggingService();

    public RoomCache()
    {
        _dicOnlineTraders = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
    }
    public void UpdateTraderCurrentRoom(string sRoom, string sTrader)
    {
        _dicOnlineTraders.AddOrUpdate(sRoom, new List<string>() { sTrader }, (x, y) => UpdateRoomOnlineTraderList(sTrader, y));
    }

    private List<string> UpdateRoomOnlineTraderList(string sTrader, List<string> aryTraderList)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!aryTraderList.Contains(sTrader))
            aryTraderList.Add(sTrader);

            return aryTraderList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logService.LogError(ex);
            return aryTraderList;
        }
    }
}
```

The above class is instantiated in the Application_Start() global.asax.cs like this:

```
public static RoomCache RoomCache;
RoomCache = new RoomCache();
```

So now between page loads my dictionary is not keeping the value i add into the list when UpdateRoomOnlineTraderList is called.  When i step through, the list is there.  The next time i load
the page it's gone and I am 100% there is nothing else removing this value from the dictionary.

How is my dictionary not retaining the value between page loads?  the key is still retained but the value just vanishes.  i'm baffled.

Comment: Do you mean that the dictionary contains the key that you had previously added, but the value is now null? Or do you mean that the dictionary element (key and value) is completely gone?

Comment: yes! that's the weird part.  the key remains in the dictionary and my value (the List<string>) is gone.  if the whole dictionary was empty i would think somewhere, somehow the object (even though static) is getting re-initialized.  but now that can't be because the key is still there and the value is null.

Comment: It is repeatable and consistent or an intermittent issue?

Comment: it's 100% repeatable.  it never works for this particular dictionary.  i have a handful of other dictionaries doing the same types of operations with same types (that's where i copied my code from!).

Comment: i should clarify one thing.  the list<string> remains in the dictionary as the value for they key, but the count is 0.  i can add keys until the cows come home and they stay, the list<string> always gets wiped and back to 0 count on each page load.

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely sure you don't have code elsewhere that's re-initializing your RoomCache or removing the expected data from it, my best guess is that you have two AppDomains running for your IIS application...so you actually have two static RoomCache's in two different AppDomains under one w3wp worker process.

You can check this yourself by printing in the watch or immediate window: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id

If the two page loads are in fact happening in different AppDomains, the result will be two different int values.

Generally, if ASP .NET has decided to host two different AppDomains for you, it's in your best interest... So, if you really need information reliably persistable across page loads, you might consider an out of process store for your information.

Alternatively, you could use your web.config to insist that ASP .NET limit your application to only one AppDomain. This still won't protect you though if ASP .NET decides to recycle your AppDomain between page loads (which may happen all the time).

Comment: Thank You Jeff. As per your suggestion, multiple AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id was being created on my API. Reason was - my API was running in multiple worker process. i have changed to 1 worker process and application started working correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the error, given the code provided. However, I have an idea.

If the list is ever returned to a caller, it's possible that the caller could then set to null... Which would then set the list in the collection to null too (since they're the same list of course).

This would cause that problem, if the `GetOnlineTradersWithSideEffects` existed.

```
public class RoomCache
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> _dicOnlineTraders;
    ILoggingService _logService = new LoggingService();
    private static readonly object SynchronousReadLock = new object();

    // This is bad because the reference is passed out to the
    // caller and we can't be sure that callers will behave. Any
    // modifications to that list will change our list too.
    private List<string> GetOnlineTradersWithSideEffects(string sRoom)
    {
        List<string> theseTraders = null;
        _dicOnlineTraders.TryGetValue(sRoom, out theseTraders);
        return theseTraders; 
    }

    // A side-effect-free method of returning the list to a caller.
    private List<string> GetOnlineTraders(string sRoom)
    {
        List<string> theseTraders = null;
        _dicOnlineTraders.TryGetValue(sRoom, out theseTraders);
        lock (SynchronousReadLock)
        {
            // Create a new list to return to a caller, that has 
            // copies of the elements of the list in the dictionary.
            var localCopy = new List<string>(theseTraders);
            return localCopy;
        }
    }

    public RoomCache()
    {
        _dicOnlineTraders = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
    }
    public void UpdateTraderCurrentRoom(string sRoom, string sTrader)
    {
        _dicOnlineTraders.AddOrUpdate(sRoom, new List<string>() { sTrader }, (x, y) => {});
    }

    private List<string> UpdateRoomOnlineTraderList(string sTrader, List<string> aryTraderList)
    {
        try
        {
            // Lock here too, when modifying the list so that our reads 
            // wait for writes and vice-versa.
            lock (SynchronousReadLock)
            {
                if (!aryTraderList.Contains(sTrader))
                    aryTraderList.Add(sTrader);
                return aryTraderList;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logService.LogError(ex);
            return aryTraderList;
        }
    }
}
```